# Dealing with a lot of repetition in data table

Tags: css, html, data-visualisation, tables

I have a table where a lot data is repeated (see the competition, players and date columns).

[image: table with repeating columns]

The endless rows of the same stuff draws the eye and makes it seem like the most important thing in the table and distracts from the interesting (varying) stuff.

Is the a good way to display the same information over over like this? It does vary further down the table.

Answer (score 2):

If they are often grouped, then using some indication that this is all the same and only printing the label on the first one could work, would take some handy coding though. 
The other option that came to mind was to simply make any repeated line have less contrast (possibly return to full contrast on hover?).

**Something Like These**
[image: Example of treating repeated info in Table]

Comment: Good ideas, thanks. A pale background color will really make it obvious what is going on there.

Answer (score 1):

Luke's suggestion is good. Another option, if space and the data allows, is to have 'Penny Dreadful Thursdays 1.01' vertical. But that would break quickly if there aren't enough entries. Looking at the chart too it may not be necessary to have a Top 8 - simply have a dividing line between the two.
Of course, if the data is able to be sorted by any other column all our ideas break ;)

Comment: Interesting idea. The table *is* sortable by all of its columns but I am considering writing the all-singing all-dancing javascript solution to make sure it always looks right post-sort. If I can work out what "looks right" is :)

Comment: Wow. That's going to be the Cirque du Soleil of JavaScript  Good luck!

Comment: I ended up with this that adds the class 'repeat' to any cell that has the same text as the cell above:

    var current, previous;
    $(this).find('td').find('\*').addBack().removeClass('repeat');
    $(this).find('tr').each(function() {
        current = $(this).find('td').toArray();
        if (previous) {
            for (i = 0; i < current.length; i++) {
                if ($(current[i]).text() == $(previous[i]).text()) {
                    $(current[i]).find('\*').addBack().addClass('repeat');
                }
            }
        }
        previous = current;
    })

Comment: This ended up taking up to 2 seconds on really big tables (10,000 rows) so I just removed it from the site. Sad, but I want the 2 seconds back :)